# dynamic memory allocation problem

Tags: c, malloc

I am working on a program that requires me to make use of 4 matrices sized [1000][1000].
 I have created them using `malloc()`, but when I try running the program it just crashes and the memory usage shoots up to 2.5 GB.  Please suggest any solution as soon as possible.  I would be grateful..

Comment: Can you show the code you run to create those matrices? What is the type of the element in each matrix? Have you tried creating smaller matrices and seeing how high the memory usage goes?

Comment: We need much more information to suggest solutions.  Post code.

Comment: Agreed. CODECODECODE! =D

Comment: Is the element type in the array around 625 bytes in size by any chance?

Comment: Also, would the program crash if you allocate the matrices on the stack?

Comment: Nothing one can help unless you specify in detail what kind of matrix, for int or for your_own_struct? It's not even clear why the program crashed. You should create smaller matrices to see if memory is an issue. If your element is 2KB in size, sorry that's too large!

Answer (score 1):

> 4 matrices sized [1000][1000]

Why use `malloc()` when you know at compile time how much memory you need? Dynamically allocating two-dimentional arrays is not the most trivial thing to do, neither is freeing them (see the C FAQ, [Question 2.14](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html#2-14) on one way to do this). Do not over-complicate your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run the program inside a debugger, such as `gdb`, to see exactly where it crashes? It will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I disagree with this being down-voted... given the information present, I think that's about the best answer one could give. =P

Comment: Being the "best answer one can give" doesn't necessarily make it a particularly good answer, though.  Personally, I wouldn't downvote it, but I wouldn't be inclined to upvote it either.